# Python - Open a file with a wildcard (%) directory path in Windows

Tags: python, windows, file

In Python, I'm trying to open a file that gets saved to the %TEMP% directory.  I've tried:

```
file = open("%TEMP%\file.txt")
```

and

```
file = open("%%TEMP%%\file.txt")
```

and

```
file = open("%TEMP%\\file.txt")
```

and

```
file = open("%%TEMP%%\\file.txt")
```

And always get (this one specifically for that last example):

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%%TEMP%%\\file.txt'
```

For sanity's sake, from Windows command prompt I do a `type %TEMP%\file.txt` and it prints out the file OK.  Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [os.environ](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os#os.environ)

```
import os
f = open(os.path.join(os.environ['TEMP'], 'file.txt'))
```

You can also use [os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path#os.path.expandvars)

```
import os
f = open(os.path.expandvars(r'%TEMP%\file.txt'))
```

Comment: deleted my answer since yours now covers expandvars :) +1